# How to create a custom theme for Admin Panel in magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3

I am trying to create a custom theme for admin panel in magento 2.3.0.
Below are the steps which i have followed:

***1) Created a folder structure in***

```
app/design/adminhtml/Vendor name/theme name
```

***2) Added theme.xml and added below code:***

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Title</title>
    <parent>Magento/backend</parent>
</theme>
```

***3) Added registration.php and added below code:***

```
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::THEME, 'adminhtml/vendor name/theme name', __DIR__);
```

***4) Added a module to change admin panel login logo:***

> added Magento_Backend folder
>
> added layout folder
>
> added admin_login.xml and below code into it

```
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-login" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">images/Logo_Icon_Black.svg</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
 </page>
```

***5) after creating above folders trying to run below commands***

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Still my changes are not getting relfected. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_apply.html

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html

Comment: I have followed the steps from the above links only for creating theme. 
Just by creating the theme for admin is enough to change the UI i guess.

Answer (score 0):

After create a theme, you have to Create a Module to Declare Theme.

Step 1: Create the registration.php file

> app/code/Vendor/Backend/registration.php

```
<?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,    
    'Vendor_Backend',__DIR__);
?>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Backend/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Backend" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence><module name="Magento_Theme"/></sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Backend/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">       
        <arguments>
            <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">Vendor/ThemeName</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

And then run commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

**You can refer this URLs,**

Create a theme:

```
 https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html
```

Apply theme:

```
 https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_apply.html
```